# Javascript interactive timeline

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an interactive timeline like [***this***](http://time.graphics/updates/new).

How can you tell what language these were developed with? There is scrolling developed. What technologies? Flash, silverlights, java, jQuery.. Maybe there are some free js-library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many libraries written in JavaScript/jQuery for this feature.
https://timeline.knightlab.com/ you can look at this URL, and search in Google for "timeline library javascript".